# How to install laravel 3 bundle in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

How to install laravel 3 bundle in laravel 4 ?

I there a way out to do so ? I have found a laravel 3 bundle but I am using laravel 4, & it does not provide the laravel 4 package.

Comment: you need to modify the bundle. what bundle you are talking about?

Comment: charisma bundle.  http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/charisma

Comment: I had made it running once, but I don't remember how. I wanted to do it again in a fresh installation.